# Typo3 filepath to url

Tags: php, typo3

My Typo3 extension can generate a file, which is saved in a directory and a database field is updated with this full filepath, which might look like this :

```
/var/www/website/fileadmin/user_upload/extension/gen/generated.xlsx
```

I wish to serve this file over http, so I need to access `http://example.com/fileadmin/user_upload/extension/gen/generated.xlsx`. What is the best way in Typo3 to do so?

I obviously wish to do this in a way that doesn't hard code the document root, so that I can install my extension on a different Typo3 instance.

Is there a function in Typo3  (4.5.22) that allows me to pass in a file path, and get back a url that I can use in the browser to download the file? Or should I look to normal php functions to do so?

**Edit**: My first version of this question was a bit under developed. I don't need someone to explain replacing DOCUMENT_ROOT with /, I was wondering whether typo3 has a utility function for this.

Comment: That's constructive. The whole point of a question is that I don't know something. Kind of the definition of ignorance. Try pointing in the right direction, at least.

Comment: Anyway, I've updated the question. I hope it meets your standards.

Comment: You still don't ask in context of your plugin... how is it created , with old pi1 approach, or Extbase ? is this file saved by extension to the disk before it's available to download, or maybe you want to serve content of some method directly from controller with header content-disposition? All that is possible, anyway, you need to describe your current... situation. ie. Maholtz gave you proper answer, but it doesn;t fit your requirements, anyway you still didn't describe'em. Try again with my advices, so I'll revert my downvote (and probably somebody will help you)

Comment: PS; and don't be angry for me - if you'll return to your first version of question after some time, you'll realize it's totally un-answerable!

Comment: The truth is that I posted the question just before passing the door of the office. Also I was handed a half completed Typo3 extension to get working for tomorrow, and have no prior experience on the platform. I wasn't even aware that there were two different ways of making plugins. But this one uses the p1 approach, I presume, as the main class ends with _p1.

Comment: @ravloony: Pity that the first version of your question had such a poor form because the current version doesn't deserve to be closed.

Comment: Meh. I got my answer. And the question remains accessible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `PATH_site` constant for that.

```
$file = 'generated.xlsx'; // this one probably fetched dinamically...
$fullpath =  PATH_site . 'fileadmin/user_upload/extension/gen/' . $file;
```

Also you can try with common `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

All TYPO3 constants are described in [TYPO3 API overview](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/GlobalValues/Constants/Index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Within TypoScript:

```
10 = TEXT
10.value = download this file
10.typolink.parameter = fileadmin/filepath/to/file.txt
```

Comment: Unfortunately the file is generated by my plugin, so I can't do that.